# Insert UTF symbol into Mysql using Hex notation

Tags: mysql, utf

How can I insert this symbol () into a MySql string *using hex notation*? I don't want to copy and paste the emoji, I want to use the Hex notation found here: https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect/hex/1F60D

I'm looking for something similar to this:

`update table set column = concat('This is an emoji:',0x1F60D );`

My server and column are UTF ready - utf8mb4_unicode_ci. If I copy the emoji and paste it, everything works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure your hex code is correct. But in general, you can do like this:

```sql
CONCAT('This is an emoji:', CAST(0xF09F988D AS CHAR))
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uk3aqtjrsRKdZXWuCGwcb8/1

Comment: Grazie! I'm not Italian, but your help has made me feel special: 0xF09FA4A9